# window.open to open PDF shows about blank page

Tags: javascript, pdf, window.open

with reference to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771425/window-open-with-pdf-stream-instead-of-pdf-location) I am developing the script which can open the PDF in next tab in the browser. I have a string which needs to be shown as PDF. I Tried this piece of code for showing the PDF in page

```
    window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + "37,80,68,70,45,49,46,52,13,37,226,227,207,211,13,10,49,56,56,32,48,32,111,98,106,13,60,60,47,76,105,110,101,97,114,105,122,101,100,32,49,47,76,32,49,50,50,56,55,54,47,79,32,49,57,48,47,69,32,57,52,50,49,56,47,78,32,52,47,84,32,49,50,50,52,56,49,47,72,32,91,32,53,48,52,32,50,55,50,93,62,62,13,101,110,100,111,98,106,13,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,13,10,50,48,57,32,48,32,111,98,106,13,60,60,47,68,101,99,111,100,101,80,97,114,109,115,60,60,47,67,111,108,117,109,110,115,32,53,47,80,114,101,100,105,99,116,111,114,32,49,50,62,62,47,70,105,108,116,101,114,47,70,108,97,116,101,68,101,99,111,100,101,47,73,68,91,60,50,48,68,52,65,69,67,50,55,67,54,53,54,68,52,65,66,53,57,57,53,69,66,49,68,50,65,51,65,50,51,51,62,60,53,69,52,49,57,57,56,48,48,69,54,67,68,66,52,66,56,69,69,68,54,56,69,68,55,51,66,66,69,50,53,67,62,93,47,73,110,100,101,120,91,49,56,56,32,52,52,93,47,73,110,102,111,32,49,56,55,32,48,32,82,47,76,101,110,103,116,104,32,49,48,49,47,80,114,101,118,32,49,50,50,52,56,50,47,82,111,111,116,32,49,56,57,32,48,32,82,47,83,105,122,101,32,50,51,50,47,84,121,112,101,47,88,82,101,102,47,87,91,49,32,51,32,49,93,62,62,115,116,114,101,97,109,13,10,104,222,98,98,100,96,16,96,96,98,96,96,254,1,34,25,166,130,72,198,96,16,201,110,1,102,111,5,203,198,129,217,154,32,146,233,54,136,100,241,6,179,67,192,108,115,176,26,15,176,8,88,13,203,57,48,233,138,196,222,15,86,147,9,34,167,88,1,73,198,101,27,128,228,255,73,191,25,152,128,110,0,155,6,180,97,0,200,255,12,140,150,111,0,2,12,0,231,249,16,83,13,10,101,110,100,115,116,114,101,97,109,13,101,110,100,111,98,106,13,115,116,97,114,116,120,114,101,102,13,10,48,13,10,37,37,69,79,70,13,10,32,13,10,50,51,49,32,48,32,111,98,106,13,60,60,47,67,32,49,56,50,47,70,105,108,116,101,114,47,70,108,97,116,101,68,101,99,111,100,101,47,73,32,50,48,54,47,76,101,110,103,116,104,32,49,55,56,47,79,32,49,54,54,47,83,32,57,55,62,62,115,116,114,101,97,109,13,10,104,222,98,96,96,96,97,96,96,234,5,145,252,204,12,130,12,8,32,8,20,99,5,98,142,15,76,235,182,50,206,117,96,96,188,56,97,230,116,136,156,75,225,132,45,115,152,128,196,172,69,130,66,93,45,14,12,12,140,22,13,64,34,2,136,197,26,24,152,59,224,58,128,138,249,25,24,247,79,4,210,194,64,44,10,210,205,168,201,32,192,160,197,202,207,208,195,104,10,228,110,98,86,98,212,102,226,99,146,103,100,96,90,202,44,195,180,148,105,26,147,195,100,193,37,237,12,25,12,225,76,37,48,215,48,30,89,7,210,11,68,133,64,90,136,129,241,152,60,144,102,98,96,224,96,1,211,172,11,128,206,96,16,99,96,188,147,0,85,199,4,16,96,0,213,79,33,243,13,10,101,110,100,115,116,114,101,97,109,13,101,110,100,111,98,106,13,49,56,57,32,48,32,111,98,106,13,60,60,47,77,97,114,107,73,110,102,111,60,60,47,77,97,114,107,101,100,32,116,114,117,101,62,62,47,77,101,116,97,100,97,116,97,32,50,48,32,48,32,82,47,79,117,116,108,105,110,101,115,32,52,52,32,48,32,82,47,80,97,103,101,76,97,121,111,117,116,47,79,110,101,67,111,108,117,109,110,47,80,97,103,101,115,32,49,56,54,32,48,32,82,47,83,116,114,117,99,116,84,114,101,101,82,111,111,116,32,53,49,32,48,32,82,47,84,121,112,101,47,67,97,116,97,108,111,103,62,62,13,101,110,100,111,98,106,13,49,57,48,32,48,32,111,98,106,13,60,60,47,65,110,110,111,116,115,32,50,49,48,32,48,32,82,47,67,111,110,116,101,110,116,115,91,49,57,54,32,48,32,82,32,49,57,56,32,48,32,82,32,49,57,57,32,48,32,82,32,50,48,49,32,48,32,82,32,50,48,50,32,48,32,82,32,50,48,51,32,48,32,82,32,50,48,52,32,48,32,82,32,50,48,53,32,48,32,82,93,47,67,114,111,112,66,111,120,91,48,46,48,32,49,50,52,48,55,46,49,32,54,49,50,46,48,32,49,51,49,57,57,46,49,93,47,77,101,100,105,97,66,111,120,91,48,46,48,32,49,50,52,48,55,46,49,32,54,49,50,46,48,32,49,51,49,57,57,46,49,93,47,80,97,114,101,110,116,32,49,56,54,32,48,32,82,47,82,101,115,111,117,114,99,101,115,60,60,47,70,111,110,116,60,60,47,84,84,48,32,50,49,53,32,48,32,82,47,84,84,49,32,50,49,55,32,48,32,82,47,84,84,50,32,50,49,57,32,48,32,82,47,84,84,51,32,50,50,49,32,48,32,82,47,84,84,52,32,50,50,51,32,48,32,82,47,84,84,53,32,50,50,53,32,48,32,82,47,84,84,54,32,50,50,55,32,48,32,82,62,62,62,62,47,82,111,116,97,116,101,32,48,47,83,116,114,117,99,116,80,97,114,101,110,116,115,32,48,47,84,121,112,101,47,80,97,103,101,62,62,13,101,110,100,111,98,106,13,49,57,49,32,48,32,111,98,106,13,60,60,47,70,105,108,116,101,114,47,70,108,97,116,101,68,101,99,111,100,101,47,70,105,114,115,116,32,49,56,48,47,76,101,110,103,116,104,32,49,52,57,51,47,78,32,50,49,47,84,121,112,101,47,79,98,106,83,116,109,62,62,115,116,114,101,97,109,13,10,104,222,164,87,105,111,219,70,16,253,43,251,49,65,98,113,239,163,8,12,216,78,141,184,117,156,34,206,209,192,48,2,70,102,108,182,146,40,80,116,28,247,215,247,205,46,21,73,12,37,203,10,132,213,222,51,179,179,111,103,30,165,224,140,51,41,4,147,6,149,100,194,162,41,20,147,65,163,214,76,43,154,54,204,58,170,45,19,220,210,132,99,66,58,137,134,103,194,105,106,4,38,130,177,76,74,172,83,150,26,36,147,118,73,76,59,204,75,73,98,21,254,164,102,74,115,200,129,82,101,21,52,75,203,52,247,52,226,72,37,182,74,207,180,245,180,61,48,237,72,41,44,209,30,230,93,144,185,156,189,141,246,166,90,81,125,249,226,69,118,16,55,162,147,29,158,163,123,142,223,187,251,105,145,29,86,245,85,81,103,31,25,223,223,111,59,23,116,114,126,153,189,202,78,178,183,197,176,185,16,158,15,12,157,67,122,174,7,48,154,135,129,9,130,250,194,13,236,101,118,222,212,183,195,230,175,188,46,38,13,19,217,249,237,151,134,100,159,150,147,127,147,150,131,201,164,106,246,247,91,59,194,142,118,40,99,6,70,147,131,57,31,8,248,69,13,98,79,168,129,233,24,33,31,50,66,241,29,141,208,82,12,130,114,11,43,140,30,120,184,182,223,14,181,217,142,217,48,122,140,107,151,29,229,211,87,69,121,125,211,48,107,93,246,178,72,83,123,50,132,236,120,148,95,207,0,140,236,184,154,52,135,135,213,247,139,61,33,128,79,154,100,66,57,21,37,92,198,233,227,124,92,142,238,159,28,229,227,47,117,153,63,77,99,229,168,160,91,179,241,200,52,114,150,143,139,236,236,195,167,55,175,79,158,181,75,159,31,86,163,171,56,137,3,20,205,240,38,59,171,234,113,62,138,67,31,147,101,56,113,118,210,228,163,114,120,48,185,30,21,140,227,176,197,248,3,19,154,167,163,209,90,50,189,46,167,77,85,103,127,183,39,210,94,199,243,30,230,179,130,150,244,170,254,125,50,172,174,202,201,117,246,177,156,28,76,102,229,143,254,113,89,207,154,163,155,188,102,74,118,52,196,151,72,135,58,205,219,37,66,248,31,46,127,87,223,22,209,172,119,213,251,73,9,105,5,158,98,124,25,11,107,161,237,170,185,153,93,208,243,164,159,21,158,241,158,159,84,178,119,188,251,179,70,162,8,102,28,61,61,227,126,150,102,93,96,54,152,212,182,36,213,170,16,255,117,175,68,131,48,64,175,77,219,128,218,161,47,224,8,203,12,44,166,190,18,105,159,226,164,203,34,122,152,118,37,194,130,37,128,6,196,18,51,223,123,185,138,60,35,150,144,231,228,18,242,20,87,115,228,201,37,228,25,203,227,28,46,93,187,40,96,5,120,31,138,250,42,159,180,192,139,48,107,71,30,128,150,94,3,173,32,55,34,203,104,179,138,172,185,182,29,209,100,59,104,146,114,51,154,84,63,154,20,80,160,2,221,139,255,129,39,137,91,65,176,136,37,141,43,155,122,84,211,253,219,173,202,66,70,68,135,38,36,89,31,37,4,207,156,19,88,37,129,60,131,54,10,176,136,144,149,214,26,199,188,86,204,105,172,243,14,88,81,169,6,26,73,130,197,241,29,246,82,59,120,160,212,99,92,152,46,126,145,132,44,50,150,145,109,29,44,163,243,82,219,82,18,115,148,196,128,194,32,99,59,184,52,110,185,139,107,128,74,228,50,218,77,30,162,25,90,73,254,160,58,22,105,58,40,117,242,177,40,53,115,148,58,238,162,128,237,80,250,75,81,208,217,7,176,234,123,177,250,75,225,207,119,1,43,54,3,214,172,1,172,78,225,205,91,215,27,132,20,2,137,245,97,171,16,232,16,212,28,152,140,87,4,76,21,193,46,34,84,109,187,34,0,128,30,209,195,155,118,135,143,97,48,254,59,219,31,6,173,165,163,26,239,1,87,64,147,158,14,248,19,181,29,216,78,178,223,2,252,212,66,84,242,113,216,70,116,135,88,52,197,63,60,88,13,50,22,231,160,60,184,24,121,77,55,42,114,187,140,55,97,151,240,38,77,31,222,44,2,44,205,33,203,114,30,5,172,224,237,0,89,110,180,132,182,216,223,49,34,122,191,25,101,34,172,162,44,233,218,13,94,146,175,194,75,61,16,14,245,154,228,234,124,199,193,114,57,237,24,39,22,14,6,181,237,37,60,184,108,154,139,33,132,246,175,210,157,234,182,46,139,154,157,21,119,75,94,110,71,49,184,163,171,31,162,53,82,173,186,122,73,225,142,254,150,221,231,108,54,59,220,245,59,220,114,138,211,169,204,163,246,250,178,88,247,243,76,119,255,250,181,235,165,63,60,182,144,219,111,215,182,154,182,181,105,147,23,240,191,2,214,96,245,50,57,199,173,45,37,31,215,155,124,144,119,104,14,215,167,57,237,239,80,243,81,9,214,187,74,205,221,42,53,127,253,254,228,229,167,63,159,181,75,119,13,20,15,160,215,186,85,244,118,148,238,136,96,253,40,6,37,57,95,199,199,83,178,208,97,193,160,41,159,83,153,247,240,45,77,60,203,131,11,195,129,219,20,105,87,249,184,65,252,55,196,85,136,159,128,233,104,164,23,226,203,173,6,17,34,91,65,2,51,96,66,72,95,137,175,71,187,218,85,6,9,211,135,190,132,165,73,54,50,130,142,92,201,196,147,40,142,26,73,138,250,233,59,88,155,212,114,33,173,54,145,27,81,150,86,26,188,29,188,95,17,255,167,253,56,171,35,27,21,229,48,120,34,152,29,184,124,176,75,64,37,49,45,151,71,126,223,158,203,63,79,112,123,36,46,247,132,218,50,133,173,33,245,115,181,59,34,211,62,138,42,73,238,215,115,123,190,134,36,233,173,8,82,231,251,206,37,134,61,103,233,139,136,151,144,158,184,125,164,77,189,56,35,62,206,87,216,56,37,73,25,153,117,251,229,209,97,225,188,195,193,121,252,190,228,169,78,152,58,207,222,191,61,161,242,228,166,105,166,191,101,217,221,221,221,224,107,51,173,38,163,114,82,12,134,213,56,251,54,27,103,120,190,234,51,200,210,56,191,206,255,195,68,246,181,200,155,219,186,152,101,179,124,148,215,247,179,219,250,91,113,159,61,93,47,115,92,14,235,106,86,125,109,162,76,236,68,10,29,210,126,92,81,113,149,122,217,105,9,24,207,232,134,143,206,49,62,253,252,199,121,188,214,207,71,167,39,131,241,108,250,125,147,130,106,82,237,77,235,234,159,98,152,116,96,237,255,2,12,0,119,83,95,235,13,10,101,110,100,115,116,114,101,97,109,13,101,110,100,111,98,106,13,49,57,50,32,48,32,111,98,106,13,60,60,47,70,105,108,116,101,114,47,70,108,97,116,101,68,101,99,111,100,101,47,76,101,110,103,116,104,32,51,5");
```

when i run this code in firebug it shows `about:blank` page. What is wrong in my code??? 
`37,80 .........51,5`  is byte []. Please suggest me what to do?

Comment: that is not a base64 encoded string, you need to convert the byte array to base64

Answer (score 1):

Use something like that:

`window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + window.btoa("YOUR_BYTE_STRING"));`