# View returned PDF from an AJAX Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have a Servlet that returns a PDF (Jasper Report).
When the request comes from an HTML Form, It successfully shows the PDF.

```
<form method="post" action="../reports/GenerateReport" target="_blank">
```

I'm new to jQuery and I would like to generate the report using an AJAX request, I now have the following code:

```
$.post('../reports/GenerateReport', {
    ...
}, function (report) {
    //this ajax call returns a PDF
    //how do I show it?
});
```

But I don't know what to do with the returned PDF. How do I show it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following post if it helps in your situation.

[window-open-with-pdf-stream-instead-of-pdf-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771425/window-open-with-pdf-stream-instead-of-pdf-location)

Alternately, you can first write this pdf to some server location and then it can be opened using

```
var script = "window.open('" + pdflocation + "', '_blank');";
```