# From VB pdf byte array to a (Javascript,HTML5) pdf

Tags: javascript, vb.net, html, pdf, arrays

I tried to display (or download) a .pdf in a webbrowser with Javascript from a byte array. I built my code from this post:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401006/show-a-pdf-stream-in-a-new-window
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR Request URL Too Long HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.
```

My code uses an $ajax call to a VB WebMethod and receive a base64String (.pdf). The .pdf is generated by an SSRS report server.

VB

```
Public Function testPDF(data As String) As String

    Try
        Dim strReportUser As String = Bidon.utilisateur
        Dim strReportUserPW As String = Bidon.motDePasse
        Dim strReportUserDomain As String = Bidon.domaine
        Dim sTargetURL As String = "an URL" + data
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(sTargetURL)
        req.PreAuthenticate = True
        req.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(strReportUser, strReportUserPW, strReportUserDomain)
        Dim HttpWResp As HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse()
        Dim fStream As Stream = HttpWResp.GetResponseStream()
        Dim fileBytes As Byte() = ReadFully(fStream)
        Return System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "[exception : " + ex.ToString() + "]")
    End Try

    Return Nothing
End Function

Public Function ReadFully(input As Stream) As Byte()

    Using MemoryStream As New MemoryStream()

        input.CopyTo(MemoryStream)
        Return MemoryStream.ToArray()

    End Using
End Function
```

JS

```
success: function (reponse) {
    var pdfwin = window.open(escape(reponse.d),"Titre","");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any solution without using .aspx ...here is it. I wish it can help someone someday.

.ASPX

```
<!-- inside body -->
        <%testPDF(a number)%>
```

VB

```
Partial Class AfficherPdf
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Public Function testPDF(data As String) As Stream

    Dim autorise As Boolean = True ' remplacer par un appel de méthode validant si l'utilisateur est autorisé à imprimer ce pdf

    If (autorise) Then 'un utilisateur ne doit pas pouvoir imprimer des factures auquelles il n'a pas accès
        Try
            Dim strReportUser As String = Bidon.utilisateur
            Dim strReportUserPW As String = Bidon.motDePasse
            Dim strReportUserDomain As String = Bidon.domaine
            Dim sTargetURL As String = "... An URL ..." + data
            Dim req As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(sTargetURL)
            req.PreAuthenticate = True
            req.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(strReportUser, strReportUserPW, strReportUserDomain)
            Dim HttpWResp As HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse()
            Dim fStream As Stream = HttpWResp.GetResponseStream()
            Dim fileBytes As Byte() = ReadFully(fStream)
            Response.Clear()
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
            Response.AddHeader(
            "content-length", fileBytes.Length.ToString())
            Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes)
            Response.Flush()
            Response.End()
            Return fStream
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "[exception : " + ex.ToString() + "]")
        End Try
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function

Public Function ReadFully(input As Stream) As Byte()

    Using MemoryStream As New MemoryStream()

        input.CopyTo(MemoryStream)
        Return MemoryStream.ToArray()

    End Using
End Function
```

End Class

JS

```
window.open("AfficherPdf.aspx","_blank");
```